# Webview postURL is sending GET instead of POST

Tags: android, webview

I am using a webview in an attempt to send a POST request via the postURL method. The following code, unfortunately is sending a GET as you would expect from loadURL. The only case I can see where this should happen is if isNetworkURL fails. I log those results, and isNetworkURL returns true. Has anyone seen this behavior or any other error with postURL in webview?

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

String nextPage = "https://my.url.com/";

String postURL = "https://my.url.com/oauth_loginx";

String postData = "next="+nextPage+"&access_token="+creds.getAccessToken();
Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to POST to this URL: " + postURL + " with these variables: " + postData);
Log.d(TAG, "POST is network URL: " + URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(postURL));
myWebView.postUrl(postURL, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));

WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: What happens if you move the postURL line to the end after `setWebViewClient`?

Comment: Why are you encoding all base64? Just send the String postData i would say.

Comment: Resolved this: apparently our server was redirecting for www.url.com to url.com which was then changing the POST to a GET. Android was not the issue here. Thanks!